# why the Identity matrix have 1's at the Main Diagonal

Tags: matrices

Could anyone explain why the 1's in the identity matrix are present in the main diagonal.

$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 8 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$ B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

while I have done the multiplication of A & B and A & C I have got the same result.Is there any other reason for selecting 1's at the main diagonal in **I**.

Comment: You got $AC=A$? If so you made a mistake.

Comment: It's mostly just because it works. We want $I$ to do certain things, and it happens that you need the matrix entries to be what they are, or else it doesn't. I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly. What are $A$, $B$, and $C$ doing?

Comment: @EricStucky:I have done a mistake.got it right know.A,B and C are matrices and just tried to multiply A with B and A with C.Realized that main diagonal produce the correct result.Is there any other reason?

Comment: @justin: Yes and no. No in that there is no *other* reason; I mean, nothing essentially different than "we want this to do a thing and oh look, this nice matrix does that thing". Yes in that there are much *deeper* reasons; i.e. it wasn't like people just sat around trying out matrices and happened to stumble upon this one. Anther way to say it is that this matrix is the one that works, but it's not an *accident* that that is true; matrices can be thought of as "avatars" of certain more ethereal objects and we know from the theory of those that it really *should* look that way in some sense.

Comment: Marc's answer gets at that deeper reason in more detail, but I can imagine that without already having some fluency in this arena it might be pretty dense.

Comment: @EricStucky:so what can I do?Do I need to send a mail to you.I really would like to know what is basis.The reason is I'm looking into Eigen values and couldn't get how the characterstic polynomial of a matrix is found.

Answer (score 2):

The identity matrix is used to express the identity linear operator $id:V\to V$ on some basis $[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$ of the vector space$~V$. In general column $j$ of such a matrix gives the coordinates, in the basis used, of the image under the operator of the basis vector $b_j$. Here the operator maps $b_j$ to itself, so the question is what are the coordinates of $b_j$ in the basis $[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$? Without knowing much about the basis vectors, you can see that the coordinates are $(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, where the $1$ is at the position ($j$) of $b_j$ in the list. Now if you put those coordinates in column $j$ of a matrix, the entry $1$ ends up on the main diagonal. Do this for every column, and you get $1$'s on the main diagonal, and $0$'s everywhere else. That's the identity matrix.

Note that this works for *any* basis, and this is a rather special property of the identity linear operator: you get the same matrix for it, no matter what basis you are using. This is why it is called *the* identity matrix.

Comment: could you explain the term 'basis vector'.

Comment: @justin, the elements of the basis.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla:does basis mean any value.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: I'm sure you meant nothing by it, but that seems to me to be a pretty disrespectful response.

Comment: @justin: If they didn't tell you what a basis is, there is no point in me trying to explain here. But without the notion of basis, talking about matrices is rather pointless. I think you are being taught linear algebra as a mysterious game (did they tell you why matrices are multiplied the way they are?), so in this approach you might as well accept the definition of identity matrix as one more mystery. But you can check that it is the only matrix such that multiplication by it (on left or right, when defined) never changes another matrix.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:but does it take time to study about 'basis'.I looked through the internet but couldn't understand what they meant.

Comment: Let me try with <600 chars. Like an amount of money is not a number, but a number together with a _currency_ as unit describes an amount, a vector is not a list of numbers, but a list of numbers together with a _basis_ as unit describes a vector. The basis itself is a list of special vectors, and each number in the list is multiplied with the corresponding basis vector, then added up, to obtain the vector they describe. The basis must be special in that _every_ vector can be so described _in one way_; the numbers then are the _coordinates_ (in this basis) of the vector they describe.

Comment: There's a Wiki page that one may want to check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:great example.Are you saying that 'basis' means more about the axis like it's direction(i,j,k) or more specifically a unit vector.

Comment: @AndreaMori: Yes, but the section "Expression of a basis" there is such rubbish that I hesitated to post that link.

Comment: @justin: Not "unit vector" in the sense of having length $1$, but a vector being _used as unit_ of measure (in the direction it points in). Geometrically you can draw axes along the directions of the basis vectors, and coordinates will then be those for that set of axes. In general there is no such thing defined as being orthogonal, and axes can be quite freely chosen. But not entirely freely; three axes should not all lie in one same plane, for instance (this is the linear independence requirement). Also one needs as many axes as the dimension of the space.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:okay got the term 'basis'.But does that mean if vector is 2-D i.e eg:(1,2) it has 2 basis?

Comment: @justin: No. In 2D _each_ basis consists of $2$ vectors. But there are infinitely many choices for a basis.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:BUt how could they may be infinitely choices for a basis if basis is a unit of vector?

Comment: @justin: Just like (in principle) there could be infinitely many different currencies.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:oh that's right.But I tried looking 'basis' in the internet.It tells about "vector space".I couldn't get it.Is 'basis' something related with identity matrix.

Comment: Just get any decent book about linear algebra. It should explain the notion "vector space" straight away, it is the context of all linear algebra. Just like the "space of (conceivable) monetary values" is the context for all finance. (You can consider my first sentence as stating a necessary condition for "decent".)

Answer (score 0):

It has to play nice with matrix multiplication.

---

Normally, things are defined like this:

Identity matrix I = 1 on *main* diagonal

Matrix multiplication L*R takes **rows** from L and **columns** from R

---

This is just an arbitrary convention. There is a way to make every theorem and use of matrices still hold true even with the identity matrix I being defined like C in your example. Call it symmetry world.

---

In symmetry world, things are defined like this (and math still works!):

Identity matrix I = 1 on *off* diagonal

Matrix multiplication L*R takes **columns** from L and **rows** from R